# Spring Cache interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-cache

There is a system that we rely on to provide information that tends to go down pretty often. Currently we use hazelcast to cache the entries with an expiry policy of 1 hour. However this has the problem that the cache entries are blindly evicted so if the system is unavailable requests will fail for a while.

I'm looking for a way to intercept spring's cache to add logic, loosely speaking I'm trying to modify the internal spring invocation from

```
Object valueFromCache = cache.getValue(cacheKey);
if (null == valueFromCache) {
    valueFromCache = cachedMethod.invokeMethod();
    cache.putValue(cacheKey, valueFromCache);
}
return valueFromCache;
```

to

```
Object valueFromCache = cache.getValue(cacheKey);
if (null == valueFromCache) {
    valueFromCache = cachedMethod.invokeMethod();
    cache.putValue(cacheKey, valueFromCache);
} else if (isValueExpired(valueFromCache)) {
    try {
        valueFromCache = cacheMethod.invokeMethod();
        cache.putValue(cacheKey, valueFromCache);
    } catch (FailedToRefreshDataException ex) {
        doWhateverWithException(ex);
    }
}
return valueFromCache;
```

Basically, I don't want to let the underlying cache provider (hazelcast in my instance) decide when to evict entries, but the application only in the case when a newer value has been acquired.

We can deal with the risk of having slightly stale data in order to get higher availability.

EDIT:
I want something that behaves similarly to the guava cachebuilder's refreshAfterWrite

For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();
    LoadingCache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .refreshAfterWrite(100, MILLISECONDS)
            .build(new CacheLoader<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String load(String value) throws Exception {
                    int intValue = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
                    if (intValue % 2 == 0) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to whatever");
                    }
                    return value + intValue;
                }
            });

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Attempt " + i + "=" + cache.get("Shoes"));
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Attempt 0=Shoes1
Attempt 1=Shoes1
Attempt 2=Shoes1
Attempt 3=Shoes3
Attempt 4=Shoes3
Attempt 5=Shoes3
Attempt 6=Shoes5
Attempt 7=Shoes5
Attempt 8=Shoes5
Attempt 9=Shoes7
```

No cache fetch failed because the 'reference system' was unavailable

Answer (score 0):

If you need `refreshAfterWrite` for Hazelcast, it's `time-to-live-seconds`.

`time-to-live-seconds` changes only when you do a `map.put` operation, so it's basically same with Guava's `refreshAfterWrite` setting.

Please see: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#map-eviction

Also, you most probably want to refresh the data in the cache after expiration. Then you can use `MapLoader` or interface. (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data)

This way, when the data expired, next call will hit `MapLoader.load`method & there you can check/get the new data from any source.

Comment: time-to-live-seconds is not what I'm looking for as mentioned in the very first sentence of my problem description. I don't want entries to be blindly evicted, I want them to be replaced only if a new version is available.

Comment: @Alexandru I just updated my answer with the `MapLoader` which is like a Guava CacheLoader but with more options.